# EXTJS Ajax request and Content-Disposition attachment

Tags: php, ajax, extjs, attachment, content-disposition

I want to get a watingmessage in extjs while loading a link. The response is a binarycode, which I want to downlad. The link is for example "test.php".

```
    function loadurl(link){

Ext.MessageBox.wait('Loading ...');
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: link,
    callback: function(options, success, response){
        Ext.MessageBox.updateProgress(1);
        Ext.MessageBox.hide();
        if (success) {
            // response : my attachment
        }
        else {

        }
    },
    scope: this
});
```

}

```
          {
                 ...


 //functioncall    
             loadurl('test.php');
      }
```

I also tried in test.php.

```
       <?php
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
          echo $content;
       ?>
```

But it doesnt work. If I just load the link it works, but without waiting message.

Comment: Maybe it is too fast? And there is no delay to show the "waiting" message?

Comment: No the waiting message is shown, but not the attachment. i've just got the response (binarycode). mabye there is a function in extjs, where i can say like attachment(binarycode,filename);

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'loading a link'? You want a loading message while the file is downloading?

Comment: No, i just want a watingmessage while loading the link. To load the link needs a few seconds for building the binary code. For that time i need a waitingmessage. And after that i just want the typical save-dialog to save the file.

Answer (score 1):

In the [ExtJS Documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.LoadMask) there is a class called `LoadMask` which is designed to show a loading 'spinner' along with a short message. In your case, you would use it like this:

```
function loadurl(link){
    var mask = Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Loading..."})
    mask.show();
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: link,
        callback: function(options, success, response){
            if (success) {
                // response : my attachment
            }
            else {

            }
            //do whatever work we need to do, then hide the mask
            mask.hide()
        },
    scope: this
});
```

However, if, for whatever reason, the callback comes back almost immediately, then it is possible that the mask will not be visible because your file loaded too fast. If this is an issue, you could force a delay by putting your Ajax request inside a `setTimeout`.